# jQuery Form Data Not Sending

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is the jQuery ajax part

```
function submitTic(){
    $('#form').html("<img src='/img/pleasewait.gif' />");
    namev = $("input[name=name]").val();
    console.log("Namev: "+namev);
    purpv = $("input[name=purp]").val();
    console.log("Purpv: "+namev);
    detailsv = $("textarea[name=details]").val();
    console.log("Detailsv: "+detailsv);
    tov = "<? echo $_GET['t'];?>";
    console.log("Tov: "+tov);
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://<?echo $location;?>/modules/Ticket/new/submit.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                name: namev,
                purp: purpv,
                details: detailsv,
                to: tov
            }
        })
        .always(function(response){
            $('#form').html(response);
        });
}
```

The form looks like this

```
<div id='form'>
<form>
<table>
    <tr><td class='left'>*Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='name' size='40' required="required"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class='left'>*Purpose:</td><td><input type='text' name='purp' maxlength="100" size='40' placeholder="Example: <?echo $placeholder;?>" required="required"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class='left'>*Details:</td><td><textarea name="details" cols="45" rows="10" maxlength="1000" required="required"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><input type='button' onclick="submitTic();" value="Submit Ticket" id='submit' ></td></tr>
</table>
<span id='reqcap'>*Required</span>
<input type="hidden" name="for" value="<? echo $_GET['t'];?>"/>
</form>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I submit the form and catch it on the other end, the only piece in the $_POST array is the "to" variable. I've tried moving the jQuery part to the data, I've tried everything short of hardcoding the variables because that would defeat the purpose of the form.

When in console, I can pull it using the $.val, but I can not assign to variable. I have no idea what's going on. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your code is XSS vulnerable. I can easily inject javascript code with changing the $_GET['t']. You have to escape it!

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string inserted. Thanks for the head's up!

Comment: That does not help by XSS... You have to escape it for javascript and html code...

Comment: ok, change mysqli_real_escape_string to addslashes. For some reason, it won't give me usable data on the real escape. However, the GET data is only going into a switch/case.

Comment: tov = "<? echo $_GET['t'];?>";

Comment: x.php?t="; virus_download_with_ajax(); "

Comment: So escape it for non word characters... Not for sql injection or html...

Comment: so something like tov = escape("<? echo $_GET['t'];?>"); is what you had in mind?

Comment: You should escape it before you use it as javascript or html code, so on server. Please read what XSS is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well judging by that code, you're trying to get the values from your form, but you've replaced the entire form with a loading image so there are no values to get. Try doing

```
namev = $("input[name=name]").val();
console.log("Namev: "+namev);
purpv = $("input[name=purp]").val();
console.log("Purpv: "+namev);
detailsv = $("textarea[name=details]").val();
console.log("Detailsv: "+detailsv);
tov = "<? echo $_GET['t'];?>";
$('#form').html("<img src='/img/pleasewait.gif' />");
```

instead. Notice the

```
$('#form').html("<img src='/img/pleasewait.gif' />");
```

is now the last thing to be done, not the first

Comment: .... That did it. I feel like a dummy now. Give me some minutes to be able to accept the answer. Waiting on the mandatory 10 to pass.

Comment: ha no worries, I do that kinda thing ALL the time :)